# torch.cuda.is_available() True in (base), but False in other conda env

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

I run this code in Anaconda prompt, and it returns True.

```
(base) C:\User
torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```

But when I run other conda environment, it just doesn't work.

```
(pytorch_project) C:\User
torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

The problem seems to be different results of **torch.version.cuda**.

(base) **torch.version.cuda** = 10.1

(pytorch_project) **torch.version.cuda** = 10.2

But I don't know why they are different...

How do I make **10.2** down to **10.1** and make **is_available() == True** ?

---

Here is my info.

```
 Windows 10 / nvidia-smi=425.31 / CUDA ver=10.1 / pytorch=1.4.0 / torchvision=0.5.0
```

[conda list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wszjM.png)

Comment: If you have the ability to update your graphics drivers to a version that supports cuda 10.2 that would also likely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers and comments. **<3**

I've solved the problem.

I use **Visual Studio Code** as the developer environment tool, but as shown in the picture I uploaded, `conda list` pointed at exact the same directory, which means **I didn't actually activate my environment**.

It should be like `(pytorch) C:\User` , but it's (Power Shell) `PS C:\User` instead.

To solve this, I went to `Settings` → `Terminal > Integrated > Shell Args: Windows` and edited `settings.json` with

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "ByPass", "-NoExit","-Command","& 'C:\\Users\\user\\miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1'" ]
```

Reference: [https://blog.lcarbon.idv.tw/vscode-設定-anaconda-路徑至-visual-studio-code-終端機中windows/](https://blog.lcarbon.idv.tw/vscode-%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A-anaconda-%E8%B7%AF%E5%BE%91%E8%87%B3-visual-studio-code-%E7%B5%82%E7%AB%AF%E6%A9%9F%E4%B8%ADwindows/)

By starting a new terminal I got `(pytorch) PS C:\User` correctly, and saw my `torch=1.5.0` using `conda list`.

Then I run `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch` to change the pytorch version.

And Voilà!!

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall PyTorch and torchvision from `pytorch_project` environment and install again in this way:

`conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch`

Or, if you prefer pip:

`pip install torch==1.6.0+cu101 torchvision==0.7.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

See https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ for details and more options.